# How can I ensure minimal CPU optimizations will be used for my GNU/C++ program and associated libraries?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation, gnu, sse

I'm checkpointing some simulations, but my jobs may be killed and resumed on other computers which relies on similar processor capabilities. For example, checkpointing with SSE4 and resuming on an old SSE2 machine will crash. Because of this I don't want my software to use anything above SSE2 (or maybe no SSE).

To ensure minimal optimization capabilities are used, do I need to statically link a manually compiled version of glibc and other libraries? Or is there an easier way to specify that required dynamic libraries should use minimal optimization capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like slowing the whole simulation down for the weakest link. You might want to investigate the [`ifunc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) function attribute for GCC, that uses a special `STT_GNU_IFUNC` ELF symbol / section. Essentially, you get function selection based on the processor. A search should come up with some more concrete examples than the GCC manual description.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I didn't know about that. Still, this would only help the code I write, and not force behavior on the libraries I call (like glibc) which would still result in a crashed job if resumed on a less capable machine.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a limited number of jobs you can run (unless you're using grid computing. e.g. with the LHCgrid) and that you have to queue your jobs and likely wait to enter the queue while other people are running jobs.  In this case, you you should use code which takes advantage of the hardware available for each job.

For SSE/AVX I recommend using Agner Fog's vectorclass http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass.  This way you use the same code but only have to compile to different SSE/AVX versions (including support for AVX2).  Then you can make a CPU dispatcher (described in the vectorclass) which determines what instruction set is available and then chooses the appropriate code path to get the best performance.  So one job runs fine on a system with only SSE2 and another job runs fine on a system with AVX2 and you don't have to write different code for each system.

If you manage to get a CPU dispatcher working let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion. I don't see how a a dispatcher would help though. The job is checkpointed (frozen) shared lib states and all. If that is restored on a machine with fewer capabilities then the job will crash even though the code would run fine if started from the beginning on that machine.